# How to Change the installation path of an android application?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing an `android` application. By default it is getting stored in

`/data/data/<package-name> path`

As my device is in warranty period, I don't have privilege to access this(root) path. So for this application I want to change the installation path e.g. to 
`/storage/emulated/0/<package-name>`

I found that in manifest.xml file using `android:installLocation` we can change installation path. But it is giving only 3 choices:

->auto

->internal

->external

But how do I change the path in internal storage ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not declare `android:installLocation` attribute, your application, by default,  will be installed on the internal storage but, you can move it to the external storage.

You can use `android:installLocation="preferExternal"` to install in external storage or
`android:installLocation="internalOnly"` for internal storage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No. I think you didn't get the question. I want to change default internal storage location to any other internal storage location.