# Change Path of the Application Data

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm developing an android application using Qt. As far as I understood the default path for deployment and installation of application is `/data/user/0/...` and this path is inaccessible unless my android device has been root. I would like to know if there is any possible way to change this path and make it accessible since I need to access some of the files in this directory.

Thank you some much for your help in advance!

Comment: Your app is not installed on that location. It's just the private directory for your app. getFilesDir(). And your app has access. Your app is installed somewhere else.

Comment: You can also use getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: `QString mDataRoot = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation).value(0);
 qDebug() << mDataRoot;` shows me `/data/user/0/...` . So it is not correct?

Comment: Your question is unclear. And you did not react on my comment.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your device is not rooted, you can not access this location from other applications. If you just want to do it for development purposes, you can simply run

```
adb root
```

from the command line to access that location from the development host and thorough the adb.
For example, you will then have access to push/pull files from that location using a command like this in Windows

```
adb pull /data/user/0/.../somesqlite.db %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is it possible to choose another path for app installation instead of /data/user/0/... ?

Comment: for example change it to /Android/data/... ?

Comment: I don't think so. read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444564/how-to-change-the-installation-path-of-an-android-application

Comment: I see. in some parts of my application, I'm using `QML` to use camera function and capture videos and these video files are saved in `file:///data/user/0/.../files/` by default. So there is no way to access these files? moving them from `/data/user/0/../files/` to another directory which is accessible in also fine. because when I change `outputLocation` of `videoRecorder` the app doesn't function anymore.